# Spock + spring boot web - get exception message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spock, spring-test

So, I'm using spring boot web and I want to test this method:

```
private void testException(HotelTvApp app) {
    throw new InternalServerException("Test message");
}
```

Returning custom exception:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public class InternalServerException extends RuntimeException {
    public InternalServerException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

A controller that invokes this method returns following JSON data:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1558423837560,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "Test message",
  "path": "/api/v1/test"
}
```

I want to write a test that will check if the exception message is correct. I tried this:

```
def "createRoom() should return 500 if trying to create room with already existing number"() {
    given:
    def uriRequest = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/api/v1/test")

    when:
    def perform = mvc.perform(get(uriRequest.toUriString()))

    then:
    perform.andExpect(status().isInternalServerError())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andExpect(jsonPath('$.message', is("Test message")))
}
```

But I get this exception:
`Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set`

How can I check the exception message here?

Comment: Can you call your endpoint with Postman and manually check what is returned and which headers?

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly set the contentType as below

```
@ExceptionHandler(OrgNotFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> exceptionHandler(final Exception ex) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body("Error");
}
```